# Save html code directly to CSV file without interpreting(Without Formatting)

Tags: php, html, css, csv

I am trying to save html code directly into a csv file. But when I save html get formated and save into csv without displaying html code:

HTML Code I am trying to save into CSV is:

```
<h3 style="text-align:justify">GREAT VISUAL</h3> 
<div style="line-height: 20.7999992370605px; text-align: justify;">SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT </div>
```

It should save the html as it is not like:

"GREAT VISUAL
SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT "

PHP code I'm using for this is:

```
$array = array();
$sub = array();
$sub['Description_1'] = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "\t"), "", $html1);
$sub['Description_2'] = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "\t"), "", $html2);

function cleanData(&$str) {
    $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
    $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
    if (strstr($str, '"'))
      $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
}

$name = date("F-j-Y-g-i-s-a") . '-OutPut';
$filename = $name . ".xls";

header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8");
$flag = false;
foreach (array_filter($array) as $row) {
   if (!$flag) {
     // display field/column names as first row
     echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n";
     $flag = true;
   }
   array_walk($row, 'cleanData');
   echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\n";
}
exit;
```

Please can anybody help me? I tried many solutions on internet but can not find any working example.

Comment: I suspect that the data is already saved the way you want it to (raw), but probably you are trying to display the result in a web browser. Such browser interprets the html tags, therefore you cannot see them. but they are still there. Try dumping the result into a file instead and take a look at that.

Comment: I am not talking about the browser. I am talking about the CSV file. When I open the file. It shoes me formatted text instead of html code.

Comment: But you are not writing a csv file. You post data to a browser and add some headers claiming that the content is a spreadsheet format (proprietary ms excel format specifically) which simply is not the case.

Comment: Meaning this is not correct way to create csv files using php?

Comment: Well it is possible to create csv data like this (though there are specific solutions for this that are more robust). But even if you do it as above: it then is csv data, not ms excel format as you claim. Those are two completely different formats. The proprietary ms excel is a binary format. Just because you can import csv data into a spreadsheet program does not mean the formats are the same.

Comment: I am not expert in it. Just trying to create csv files in php with displaying html code in it. Do you have any example code or reference question to show me about this solution?

Comment: There are other issues with that code: What is `array_filter($array)` meant to do?  Where does `$flag` come from? `$array` is never filled, ...

Comment: Well, the most straight forward approach would be to use the php function for that: `fputcsv()`. Take a look at its documentation, it also comes with examples: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: Can you please help me if you can? If this is not good? I am just trying as I said I am not expert. I am searching on internet to do so.

Comment: The suggestion I made before (`fputcsv()`) is not suitable? Why? You can find many more examples here on StackOverflow or just by searching for "php create csv" on google... You see we certainly like to help! but we can only do so for specific questions. There is little sense in us writing your code....

Comment: I didn't say that (fputcsv()) is not suitable. I am looking into it now. Thank you.

Comment: The first comment by MagicalTux will be of special interest for you if you want to output the csv directly to the browser instead of writing it to a local file on the server. But as mentioned before: use correct headers to describe fthe format, file name extension ".csv" if any and mime type "text/csv".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution. Why this huge and useless code you are using for creating CSV? 
Try this.

```
$name = date("F-j-Y-g-i-s-a") . '-OutPut';

header("Content-Type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name.csv");
// Disable caching
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies

function outputCSV($data) {
    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        fputcsv($output, $row); // here you can change delimiter/enclosure
    }
    fclose($output);
}

outputCSV($array);
```